# that's too slow to get my wall from API graph

Tags: python, performance, facebook-graph-api, graph

i want to know how much time(secend) do i need to get my whole facebook wall from json(graph api)

it takes about 190 seconds to get my whole wall's post (maybe 2000 posts and 131pages(json))

follow is python code. that code is just reading the posts.

is there any problem in my code? and should i cut my response time?

```
accessToken = "Secret"
requestURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token="+accessToken
beforeSec = time.time()*1000
pages = 1
while 1:
    read = urllib.urlopen(requestURL).read()
    read = json.loads(read)
    data = read["data"]
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        pass
    try:
        requestURL = read["paging"]["next"]
        pages+=1
    except:
        break
afterSec = time.time()*1000

print afterSec - beforeSec
```

Comment: Facebook's architecture benefits from the fact that only new "things" are accessed often. So probably no, old posts will be slower to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is synchronous, so you download the pages one by one.

It's very slow, you could download several pages in parallel instead.

Greenlet are the new hype for Python paraller computing, so give a try to [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html).

Well, this is provided you can get the next page before downloading the entire previous page of course. Try to see if you can get the next paging in a quick way.

Answer (score 1):

It depends offcourse on how big the users wall is ... They have released a new batch function : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Mayb you can use that?

Comment: You can put the limit up, this way you don't have to do manby requests, saves time!